# Adding spaces inside a math expression

Tags: spacing

I want to my statement to say u = g in Omega.  I tried coding `$$u=g in \Omega$$`, but this results in no spaces around the word 'in'.  How can I insert them?

Comment: `\textrm{ in }` or with `amsmath` `\text{ in }` or even `\in`?

Comment: Are you using plain TeX, or LaTeX? If using the latter, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy) and [Are `\(` and `\)` preferable to `$`?](http://goo.gl/ClGXg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is `$$u = g \text{ in } \Omega$$`

Or, if you don't need the display with two dollar signs, `$u = g$ in $\Omega$`

Or, if you want a bigger space, `$$u = g \quad \text{in} \quad \Omega$$`

Or, for an even bigger space, `$$u = g \qquad \text{in} \qquad \Omega$$`

Comment: Oddly enough, $$u = g \text{ in } \Omega$$ produces an undefined control sequence error...

Comment: Did you see the comment by Qrrbrbirlbel?  Did you do \usepackage{amsmath}  Try that and see if that fixes it.